# CoAP pub/sub transmision reliability

Tags: iot, publish-subscribe, coap

I´m making a work about CoAP extension that allows it to use the Publish/Subscribe Broker model and I´m currently analyzing how is the Transmision Reliabilty gets done here. In CoAP are used CONFIRMABLE and NON-CONFIRMABLE messages, to guarantee that a message arrived to destination. My cuestion is if this extension of CoAP relies on this CoAP messages to guarantee transmision reliability, because i can´t find anything that talks about this. Thank you.

Comment: Clarifying question: are you asking if the draft IETF spec "Publish-Subscribe Broker for CoAP" relies on confirmable messages to require message reliability? https://core-wg.github.io/coap-pubsub/draft-ietf-core-pubsub.html

Comment: @jonathanberi Exactly that is what I´m asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In CoAP are used CONFIRMABLE and NON-CONFIRMABLE messages, to
>   guarantee that a message arrived to destination.

CON messages are retransmitted until either the retransmission counter expires or a ACK/RST is received as answer. That makes it very probable, that the message arrives the destination, but a "guarantee" is something else. "Cut the wire" and no technology can grant, that the message arrives the destination. Receiving a ACK you could rely, that the message arrived, but if you don't receive it, you don't know it.

Retransmission consumes bandwidth, and the benefit from sending "many different" message ("unreliable") vs. "some" messages ("reliable") is application specific.
That application specific decision is also true for pubsub. I'm not sure, why pubsub should therefore explicit mention the CON/NON behavior.

Just to mention:
Such questions may be asked directly in the [IETF Core Mailinglist](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/browse/core/). There you may reach the authors of the RFC and you have a chance, to get their feedback. You will need to register there.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but perhaps I did not express myself well in the question. CoAP has an extension defined [here](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-ietf-core-coap-pubsub-09.pdf), that allows this protocol to use a pub / sub broker architecture, and what I would like to know is if this implementation despites it used new messages as part of the new REST API exposed by the broker also use for message reliability the CONFIRMABLE messages and other features of coAP to ensure reliability like the message-id and token. But i will definitely check your source, thanks.

Comment: The RFC-draft contains a mapping for the pub/sub operations to the CoAP primitives, e.g. DISCOVERY => GET {+ps}/{+topic}{?q*}. Though that mapping uses standard CoAP request (e.g. GET, PUT, or POST), CON and NON are used as usual. Same applies to the message-id or the token, nothing new introduced here. So pubsub defines, how to use CoAP, it doesn't adapt CoAP.

Answer (score 1):

CoAP *messages* are not reliable and not even transmitted end-to-end -- things like token, message ID and even observation number may change in the presence of proxies.

In particular, wherever observation is used (including pub/sub), no particular representation is guaranteed to arrive at the observer; what *is* guaranteed (and ensured by the CON messages regularly sent as part of observations) is that on the long run, the client ends up with the same representation as the server (which is also called "eventual consistency"). This is an important feature, as it allows operation even on congested networks.

To illustrate with an example, a server may send a value "14.7" in the first place, then send "14.8" in a NON, and a proxy could forward "14.8" to the client. Then the server might send "14.9" next in a CON, which the proxy acknowledges -- but maybe the proxy is busy, and delays sending the notification to the client a bit. Next, the server sends "15.0", and the proxy forwards it immediately. You see that the client never received the "14.9", even though it was CON, but it did get a later value.

Granted, not every deployment does use proxies, but it is part of the design of REST architectures that everything in them needs to work just as well if there is any.